# Right Click Run With Parameters

Tags: windows

Does anyone have any recommendations for a simple 64-bit compatible Windows program that, when you right-click an exe, bat, msi etc. file, that pops up a menu allowing you to run the file with parameters or arguments? NirExt does this task but the program has not been updated in ages. Would a registry hack or vbs or bat file accomplish the goal? FYI, I don't know much about coding but can modify the registry. Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with NirExt? It does exactly what you're asking for. It hasn't been updated in a long time, but its features are working up to the latest Windows versions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a separate software for this task, although command line will give you much more control.

The easiest will be:

- Hold Shift + right click on an empty space in the folder where your file is located
- Select "Open CMD Window here" or "Open Powershell Window here". The exact option depends on the settings on your system, but either of those will suffice.
- Execute your program by writing its name and supplying any extra arguments you want.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just create a shortcut icon on your desktop? Right-click the shortcut icon, select Properties, and on the main tab, the "Target" text field can take arguments.

This will work only if you  have a few, say 5-10, predictable arguments, repeatedly occuring, to choose from.

(untested, off the top of my head. I hope you know what I mean).